# Potentially dangerous Request caused by OutputCache filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm seeing a strange behavior in my MVC3 application. I have an Action that is called by Ajax, and receives a Post with HTML text.
I want to allow the entry of HTML, so I set the ValidateInput(false) attribute. I also have a global OutputCache filter with this parameters: (NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*" )
The code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*" )]
public ActionResult Edit(SomeModel someModel)
{
   saveModel(someModel);
   return new AjaxEditSuccessResult();
}
```

When I send a post to that method, it is executed and the model is saved, but the response I get is the standard "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error message, with this stacktrace:

```
[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (text="<p class="MsoNormal"...").]
System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +9665149
System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ValidateHttpValueCollection>b__3(String key, String value) +18
System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key) +9664565
System.Web.HttpValueCollection.Get(String name) +17
System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.CreateOutputCachedItemKey(String path, HttpVerb verb, HttpContext context, CachedVary cachedVary) +676
System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.CreateOutputCachedItemKey(HttpContext context, CachedVary cachedVary) +55
System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +9716788
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Do you know if I can indicate in any way to the OutputCache attribute that it needs to respect the ValidateInput attribute?

Answer (score 14):

There are two places in the flow where validation is invoked:

1. on controller method invokation
2. when rendered result is stored in the cache.

You have fixed first problem with `ValidateInputAttribute(false)`, but looks like cache module is ignoring the `NoStore` directive and still tries to construct the cache key and before doing that it validates the arguments, to get rid of that specify: `Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None`, so that cache module will not even try to do anything. Replace your `OutputCache[...]` with something like this:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```