# Send HTML string with MVC Form Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, json

We have MVC an application. we want to offer our customers to enter html texts for use in document generation. 
For this purpose we have included CK Editor. CK has a function to return the html. We want to 'encode' this Html, so we can place it in an input field that will be included in a form post.

What JavaScript function(s) can we use to convert the Html string to a format that we can send with the formpost. The form post is done via AJAX.

---

Update:
In an other post we found this function:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
 }
```

It looks like this will do the trick, but are there any build-in or JQuery functions that will do this?

Comment: why don't you just save html in database???

Comment: @Exception: That is exactly what we want to do, but first it has to go from the client machine to the server in the form post

Comment: yes..so..you can save exact html in database from client machine to  database...

Comment: send it as plain string only..

Comment: you can post, but what is your exact problem, if it is not reaching to your controller then you have to palce [AllowHtml] attribute to your controller method

Comment: We need to place a string (containing) html into a hidden field with the correct name so it will be included in the form post. We need javascript to convert this html into something that will not bugger up the form post.

Comment: just save html as it is in database it will not create any problem in my opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can give validate input(false) for your post method to allow ck editor content in the class object:*

```
[HttpPost]   
[ValidateInput(false)]  

public ActionResult SaveArticle(ArticleModel model)
{
    return view();
}
```

In M V C 3 you can also define your model property with html content as   [Allow Html]

```
public class Article Model 
{
    [AllowHtml]

    public string Some Property { get; set; }

    public string Some Other Property { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The question deals with the CLIENT/BROWSER side part. I'm looking for a javascript function that will take a Html string and will encoded it, so it can be set as the value of a hidden field. On the server we can use Server.HtmlDecode to reproduce the sent HTML that is not the problem

Comment: [ValidateInput(false)] works. The [Allow Html] does not, as we use the form collection at various places. This is covered in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861927/allowhtml-attribute-not-working
The points are yours.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it the long cut way by manually replacing the special characters and pass it in a hidden field?.. You can directly post the html content with your property on normal submit button by declaring the post method with validateinput(false)

Comment: this should be comment. write your response either in your replied answer or comment.